# Streaming an Image to WCF by Android

Tags: android, wcf, streaming

I have this android code to send an image file to server running WCF .
but it is returning internal server error (Code 500) . Whole code I have are these containing configuration and other ...

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="60000" maxBufferSize="60000" transferMode="Streamed" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>


      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>

  <service name="AndroidWcfService.FileUploaderService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AndroidWcfService.IFileUploaderService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

and this the interface code

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile", //"/{pointId}/{ticket}",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat =     WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]       
    int UploadFile(Stream image);
```

implementation

```
 public int UploadFile(Stream image)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] f = new byte[10000];

            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = image.Read(f, 0, f.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            byte[] t = new byte[totalBytesRead];
            Array.Copy(f, t, totalBytesRead);

            var fileName = string.Format("{0}.png", DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
            var s = File.Create(fileName);
            s.Write(t, 0, totalBytesRead);
            s.Flush();
            s.Close();


            return 1000;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteEntry("UploadFile err:" + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null) Logger.WriteEntry("UploadFile err inner exception:" +
                ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return -1000;
    }
```

and the android code is

```
 public void uploadFile(File file) {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://test.com:16024/FileUploaderService.svc/UploadFile");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    // Indicate that this information comes in parts (text and file)
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    try {

        // Create a JSON object to be used in the StringBody
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        // Add some values
        jsonObj.put("filename", file.getName());

        // Add the JSON "part"
        reqEntity.addPart("entity", new StringBody(jsonObj.toString()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v("App", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.v("App", e.getMessage());
    }

    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);// , "application/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.addPart("image", fileBody);

    try {
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // Execute the request "POST"
        HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        // Check the status code, in this case "created"
        if (((HttpResponse) httpResp).getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
            Log.v("App", "Uploaded sucessfully!");
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What's wrong here ?

Comment: Would suggest you to enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your WCF service and inspect the trace log to know the reason for the error. Also make sure that you are not sending a very big file as i see you have the maxReceivedMessageSize = 60000

Comment: BTW. It looks like you are trying to create a RESTful API. I would suggest using "ASP.Net MVC 4 - WebAPI" instead of WCF.

Comment: @Rajesh , I have enabled the tracing and this is the error it shows :The default content type mapper selected the request format, 'Raw', given the request's content-type, 'multipart/form-data; boundary=1nXZ59fnANsK58Sn9NikSq01WOW7ZF2CZL0v'.

Comment: I think it makes sense as you have explicitly set your requestType to be JSON and the request type that is being send is multipart/form-data as you are writing a stream. Can you leave the request type to default and try (i.e. remove the RequestType attribute setting in your WCF service).

Comment: @Rajesh it was without explicitly specified request type , but didnt worked so I changed to this way.

Comment: I was referring to the RequestFormat attribute in your WCF service declaration which is set to JSON.